# How to find out if an object from an array is present also in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have 2 objects that contain arrays of objects within like this:

```
var array1 = {"id":"car", "name":"honda", "virtues":[{"price":99}, {"size" : ""}, {"condition" : "new"}]};

var array2 = {'userid' : '2', 'username' : 'john','prefs' : [{"price":1}]};
```

I don't care for size all I want is price and condition so I want to find out if those are present also in array2 so I did this:

```
calceffect = function(myarray) {
 myarray.map(x => {
  for(let key in x) {
   if(key!= 'size') {
    array2.prefs.map(d => 
     {
      for(let k in d) {
       if(k == key){
        console.log('present');
       } else {
        console.log('absent');
       }
      }
     }
    );
   }
  }
 });
}

calceffect(array1.virtues); //in this case it will output 'it is present' for "price" and 'absent' for "condition"
```

It works as expected, however I find it like a little too convoluted. Is there a cleaner way to get the same result?

Comment: First: neither `array1` nor `array2` are arrays. Your question is difficult to understand.

Comment: But what do you want to achieve exactly? Just a console log? or to return some data? What is expected shape? Should it work for any two objects or only those two? If for any pair of objects, what is shape of those objects?

Comment: My goal is to add the object if not present but a console log will do fine for now.

Comment: do you have only one property in the nested arrays? please add a wanted result. btw, your arrays are objects. could you have really arrays with objects? what result do you expect then?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the keys, count and get the result

```js
const
    getKeys = a => a.flatMap(o => Object.keys(o)),
    a = { id: "car", name: "honda", virtues: [{ price: 99 }, { size: "" }, { condition: "new" }] },
    b = { userid: '2', username: 'john', prefs: [{ price: 1 }] },
    add = (object, d) => v => object[v] = (object[v] || 0) + d,
    counts = {}
    result = { common: [], unique: [] };

getKeys(a.virtues).forEach(add(counts, 1));
getKeys(b.prefs).forEach(add(counts, -1));

Object.entries(counts).forEach(([k, v]) => result[v ? 'unique' : 'common'].push(k));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a way that you can use the built in JavaScript methods such as `filter` and `some` to check if the `price` and condition properties are in array2.prefs.

One way you could refactor this is making a function that returns a boolean:

```
let array1 = {"id":"car", "name":"honda", "virtues":[{"price":99}, {"size" : ""}, {"condition" : "new"}]};

let array2 = {'userid' : '2', 'username' : 'john','prefs' : [{"price":1}]};
```

First we filter out the objects in `array1.virtues` that have a price or condition, secondly we use the `every` method to check if all objects satisfy the condition that there exists at least one object in `array.prefs` that has both a `price` and a `condition`. `some` method is used to check for the existing object.

```
let priceAndCondition = array1.virtues.filter(x => x.price || x.condition).every(x => array2.prefs.some(y => y.price && y.condition));

console.log(priceAndCondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using below code -

```
// create an array of the desired keys to check
const desiredKeys = ['price', 'condition'];

// check if each desired key is present in array2 prefs
const presentKeys = desiredKeys.filter(key => array2.prefs.some(pref => 
pref.hasOwnProperty(key)));

// output the result
presentKeys.forEach(key => console.log(`${key} is present`));
```

If you want to use array of undesired keys, then you can use below code -

```
// create an array of the desired keys to check
const unDesiredKeys = ['size'];

// check if each desired key is present in array2 prefs
const presentKeys = unDesiredKeys.filter(key => 
      array2.prefs.some(pref => !pref.hasOwnProperty(key)));

// output the result
presentKeys.forEach(key => console.log(`${key} is present`));
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a constant for NOT desired keys instead? It would be shorter.

Comment: Yes, it depends. If you think NOT desired keys are less then you can use it as well. From your question, it is hard to find out. :)

Comment: Yes, it is the former. How can I do it like that?

Comment: I have updated the response for it. @CainNuke

Comment: hmm I get `size is present`. Could you please post a working example?

Answer (score 0):

this is good?

```
var array1 = {
    "id":"car",
    "name":"honda",
    "virtues":[{"price":99}, {"size" : ""}, {"condition" : "new"}]
};

var array2 = {
    'userid' : '2',
    'username' : 'john',
    'prefs' : [{"price":1}]
};

const value1 = Object.values(array1);
const value2 = Object.values(array2);
const vObj1 = value1.filter(item => typeof item === "object");
const vObj2 = value2.filter(item => typeof item === "object");
const obj1 = vObj1[0];
const obj2 = vObj2[0];

for(let index of obj1){
    for(let index2 of obj2){
    console.log(Object.keys(index2).filter(test => test ===  Object.keys(index)[0]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error: can't convert undefined to object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).